# 5 inch vs 7 inch monitors

Tags: monitoring, monitors, studio-monitors, monitor-calibration

I'm a musician and after having started into mixing at home with nothing more than a good pair of headphones (Beyerdynamic DT 880 PRO) and an interface, I'm planning on buying some good monitors and want to decide between 5 or 7 inch woofer sizes.

I'm looking at Adam Audio. I can afford the T5V, T7V and A5X (if it's worth it).

**The Experiment**

Using my headphones and my DAW (Logic), I've made a setup with an EQ low-pass filtering to hear only lows (at 70Hz, 48dB/Oct, Q 0.71), and "modeled" the 3 speakers with an EQ hi-pass filtering to match the low-end of their response curves:

T7V

- Specs: 39Hz-25kHz, [see curve](https://www.adam-audio.com/content/uploads/2019/07/T7V_Frequency-Response-1920x1463.png)
- Model: hi-pass at 50Hz, 48dB/Oct, Q 0.60: curve crosses 40Hz at -11db and 50Hz at -3db

T5V

- Specs: 45Hz-25kHz, [see curve](https://www.adam-audio.com/content/uploads/2019/05/T5V_Frequency-Response-1920x1463.png)
- Model: hi-pass at 55Hz, 48dB/Oct, Q 0.60: curve crosses 40Hz at -15db and 50Hz at -6db

A5X

- Specs: 50Hz-50kHz (50kHz?! xD), no published curve
- Model: hi-pass at 60Hz, 48dB/Oct, Q 0.60: added 5Hz to T5V (less bass)

Tested the 3 with some music and a clip recorded with my bass. I can hear a very slight difference in the low E (41Hz), having the fundamental better represented by the T7V but I guess brains are clever and don't miss it in the other 2 simulations, since it is still there (just lower vol.) and all other harmonics are there "hinting" it's existence.

NOTE: I DO hear much more difference if I remove the "models" filters and allow all the bass to come through. Headphones are good! :)

**Other considerations**

- I'll be moving kind-of frequently, so will treat the rooms very lightly. Probably some Auralex on 1st reflections and some furniture as bass traps.
- Rooms may be small, neighbours may be complaining (walls are thin in Spain ;p).
- I'm mostly doing rock, acoustics, and other things not bass-intensive. Not much EDM or hiphop.
- My main concern is **clarity**, and that's why I'm also looking the A5X.

**The Question**

I think I'll be ok with 5's, especially to avoid room problems. For the clinical bass tweaking I can use the Beyers and for spatial imaging, dynamics and all the rest I can use the 5 inch speakers.

*Is this a good approach or I really need a 7? Many people thinks it's the absolute minimum woofer size you can have. Am I missing something?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go sit in a room with them all. Pick the one you prefer. I don't think you're going to be anywhere near critical territory on a pair of 300 quid speakers, just pick the ones that you feel best with. Note: the more extended the bass handling in that kind of price range, the more wild the room acoustics can make things.

Comment: My work monitors have 10" drivers [Genelec 1032] my home monitors have 6" [dynaudio BM6A]. The dynaudios are more portable to different rooms & better for nearfield [though the work room cost a fortune & my home room didn't]